# Jquery autocomplete search not working in usercontrol(ascx) page in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have text box in UserControle(ascx) page of Asp.net website, I use automcomplete search on this text box, this is working fine when i put this textbox on aspx page. But in ascx(usercontrol) page it is not working.

My textbox is:

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtCityUsed" Style="width: 91.2%; height: 13px; float: left;"
                                                            Width="" runat="server">
```

I am calling below two method from page load of user controle page,

```
protected void SetAutocompleteTextbox()
{
    StringBuilder sbLVAutocomplete;
    try
    {
        sbLVAutocomplete = new StringBuilder();
        sbLVAutocomplete.AppendLine("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
        sbLVAutocomplete.AppendLine("           function autoFetchRecord_txtCityUsed() {");
        sbLVAutocomplete.AppendLine("               if (document.getElementById(\"" + txtCityUsed.ClientID + "\").value.length >=1) {");
        sbLVAutocomplete.AppendLine("                   $(\"#" + txtCityUsed.ClientID + "\").autocomplete({");
        sbLVAutocomplete.AppendLine("                       source: function(request, response) {");
        sbLVAutocomplete.AppendLine("                           $.ajax({");
        sbLVAutocomplete.AppendLine("                               type: \"POST\",");
        sbLVAutocomplete.AppendLine("                               contentType: \"application/json; charset=utf-8\",");
        sbLVAutocomplete.AppendLine("                               url: \"LandingForPortal.aspx/GetListOfCity\",");
        sbLVAutocomplete.AppendLine("                               data: \"{'Name':'\" + document.getElementById('" + txtCityUsed.ClientID + "').value + \"','strRiskStartDate':'\" + document.getElementById('" + txtPolicyStartDate.ClientID + "').value + \"'}\",");
        sbLVAutocomplete.AppendLine("                               dataType: \"json\",");
        sbLVAutocomplete.AppendLine("                               success: function (data) {");
        sbLVAutocomplete.AppendLine("                                   if (data.d.length == 0){ ");
        sbLVAutocomplete.AppendLine("                                       alert('No Data Found!');");
        sbLVAutocomplete.AppendLine("                                       document.getElementById('" + txtCityUsed.ClientID + "').value =\"\";");
        sbLVAutocomplete.AppendLine("                                       document.getElementById('" + hdnVehicleUsedCityCode.ClientID + "').value =\"\";");
        sbLVAutocomplete.AppendLine("                                       document.getElementById('" + hdnVehicleUsedOfficeCode.ClientID + "').value =\"\";");
        sbLVAutocomplete.AppendLine("                                       document.getElementById('" + hdnVehicleUsedOfficeName.ClientID + "').value =\"\";");
        sbLVAutocomplete.AppendLine("                                       document.getElementById('" + hdnVehicleUsedParentOfficeCode.ClientID + "').value =\"\";");
        sbLVAutocomplete.AppendLine("                                   }");
        sbLVAutocomplete.AppendLine("                                   response($.map(data.d, function (item) {");
        sbLVAutocomplete.AppendLine("                                       return {");
        sbLVAutocomplete.AppendLine("                                           value: item.City,");
        sbLVAutocomplete.AppendLine("                                           CityCode: item.CityCode,");
        sbLVAutocomplete.AppendLine("                                           OfficeCode: item.OfficeCode,");
        sbLVAutocomplete.AppendLine("                                           OfficeLocation: item.OfficeLocation,");
        sbLVAutocomplete.AppendLine("                                           ParentOfficeCode: item.ParentOfficeCode");
        sbLVAutocomplete.AppendLine("                                       }");
        sbLVAutocomplete.AppendLine("                                   }))");
        sbLVAutocomplete.AppendLine("                                   },");
        sbLVAutocomplete.AppendLine("                                   error: function (result) {");
        sbLVAutocomplete.AppendLine("                                       alert(data);");
        sbLVAutocomplete.AppendLine("                                   }");
        sbLVAutocomplete.AppendLine("                           });");
        sbLVAutocomplete.AppendLine("                       },");
        sbLVAutocomplete.AppendLine("                       ");
        sbLVAutocomplete.AppendLine("                       open: function(){");
        sbLVAutocomplete.AppendLine("                           $('.ui-autocomplete').css('width', '300');");
        sbLVAutocomplete.AppendLine("                       },");
        sbLVAutocomplete.AppendLine("                       select: function (event, ui) {");
        sbLVAutocomplete.AppendLine("                           if (ui.item) {");
        sbLVAutocomplete.AppendLine("                               $('#" + txtCityUsed.ClientID + "').val(ui.item.value);");
        sbLVAutocomplete.AppendLine("                               $('#" + hdnVehicleUsedCityCode.ClientID + "').val(ui.item.CityCode);");
        sbLVAutocomplete.AppendLine("                               $('#" + hdnVehicleUsedOfficeCode.ClientID + "').val(ui.item.OfficeCode);");
        sbLVAutocomplete.AppendLine("                               $('#" + hdnVehicleUsedOfficeName.ClientID + "').val(ui.item.OfficeLocation);");
        sbLVAutocomplete.AppendLine("                               $('#" + hdnVehicleUsedParentOfficeCode.ClientID + "').val(ui.item.ParentOfficeCode);");
        sbLVAutocomplete.AppendLine("                               return false;");
        sbLVAutocomplete.AppendLine("                           }");
        sbLVAutocomplete.AppendLine("                       },");
        sbLVAutocomplete.AppendLine("                       minLength: 3");
        sbLVAutocomplete.AppendLine("                   });");
        sbLVAutocomplete.AppendLine("               }");
        sbLVAutocomplete.AppendLine("           }");
        sbLVAutocomplete.AppendLine("</script>");

        if (!Page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("Autocomplete"))
        {
            //Registering startup script Autocomplete
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(string), "Autocomplete", sbLVAutocomplete.ToString());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //ErrorMessage("ERROR", "ERROR from SetAutocompleteTextbox()" + ex.Message);

    }
    finally
    {
    }
}
protected void AddAttributesAutoComplete()
{
    try
    {
        txtCityUsed.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "autoFetchRecord_txtCityUsed();");

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //  ErrorMessage("ERROR", "ERROR from AddAttributesAutoComplete()" + ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
    }
}
```

**This is the method which get call when i enter search text in textbox**

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static object GetListOfCity(string Name, string strRiskStartDate)
{
    ServiceResult arrLVServiceResult;
    GCIntegrationClient objCVGCIntegrationClient = new GCIntegrationClient();
    arrLVServiceResult = objCVGCIntegrationClient.CityWherePrimarilyUsedLOV_GetObjectData(Convert.ToString(strProductCode), Convert.ToString(strTokenId), Convert.ToString(strRiskStartDate), Convert.ToString(""), Convert.ToString(Name));
    return arrLVServiceResult.UserData.CityGrid;
}
```

But when i enter search text for autocomplete search in usercontrol(ascx) page then above method didn't get call but page_load occured. while pageload should not occure and only this above method should get call....
please any body help me...I can not change the page and can't use popup for autosearch

Comment: where'd you call or use the `UserControl` from? are you calling it from page `LandingForPortal.aspx` or from other page?

Comment: My user control page name is LandingPageForPortalUserControl.ascx but it  open in LandingForPortal.aspx so i have written page name LandingForPortal.aspx, what page name should i use....??

Comment: did your script registered succesfully? Try adding some alert, and did the page reload right after `keyup`? Try press the key and hold it, did the page reload or did it trigger the `PageLoad` then?

Comment: Is there any reason why you have to push the js from code behind? Just place it on your aspx page to eliminate any issues with the script registration. If that works, then move things back to code behind.

Comment: yaa....we were told that don't write the code directly from aspx...

Comment: Thank for applying Kyojimaru...it hit pageLoad when i enter the searchtext...that should not hit it should hit directly GetListOfCity method.